# Center matplotlib colormap on a specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colormap

I'm making plots using matplotlib colormap "seismic" and would like to have the white color centered on 0. When I run my script with no changes, white falls from 0 to -10. I tried then setting vmin=-50, vmax=50 but I completely lose the white in that case. Any suggestions on how to accomplish that?

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
nc = NetCDFFile('myfile.nc')
lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc.variables['lon'][:]
time = nc.variables['time'][:]
hgt = nc.variables['hgt'][:]
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=180.,llcrnrlat=0.,urcrnrlon=320.,urcrnrlat=80.)
lons,lats = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
x,y = map(lons,lats)
cs = map.contourf(x,y,hgt[0],cmap='seismic')
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs, orientation='horizontal', shrink=0.5, 
cmap='seismic')
cbar.set_label('500mb Geopotential Height Anomalies(m)')
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawparallels(np.arange(20,80,20),labels=[1,1,0,0], linewidth=0.5)
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(200,320,20),labels=[0,0,0,1], linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Plot with defaults:
[image: Plot with defaults]

Plot with vmin, vmax set:
[image: Plot with vmin, vmax set]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the levels you want to show manually. As long as you have the same spacing of intervals to the left and to the right of zero this works nicely.

```
levels = [-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,10,20,30,40,50]
ax.contourf(X,Y,Z, levels)
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-6.3,6.3)
y = np.linspace(-3.1,3.1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = -np.cos(X)*np.cos(Y)*45

levels = [-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,10,20,30,40,50]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2))
cont = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z,levels, cmap="seismic")
fig.colorbar(cont, orientation="horizontal")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, if you want the colorbar to be proportional to the data,

```
fig.colorbar(cont, orientation="horizontal", spacing="proportional")
```

[image]

If levels are unequal, you need to specify `vmin` and `vmax`.

```
levels = [-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,10,30,50,80,100]
cont = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z,levels, cmap="seismic", vmin=-50, vmax=50)
```

[image]

The disadvantage is that you loose resolution, hence you may use a BoundaryNorm to select equally spaced colors for unequally spaced labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-6.3,6.3)
y = np.linspace(-3.1,3.1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = -np.cos(X)*np.cos(Y)*45

levels = [-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,10,30,50,80,100]
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(levels, len(levels)-1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2))
cont = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z,levels,cmap=plt.get_cmap("seismic",len(levels)-1), norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(cont, orientation="horizontal")
plt.show()
```

[image]

To change the ticklabels on the colorbar so something other than the levels or in case they are too dence you may use the `ticks` argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-6.3,6.3)
y = np.linspace(-3.1,3.1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = -np.cos(X)*np.cos(Y)*45

levels = np.arange(-45,50,5)
levels = levels[levels!=0]
ticks=np.arange(-40,50,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2))
cont = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z,levels,cmap="seismic", spacing="proportional")
fig.colorbar(cont, orientation="horizontal", ticks=ticks, spacing="proportional")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Explicitly setting the levels accomplished what I wanted. However, my colorbar now shows a mid point of 0 and the labels are every 15 units (-45,-30,-15,0,15,30,45). How can I specify that the colorbar labels appear in increments of 10, going from -50 to 50?

Comment: The labels follow the levels. This is shown in this answer.

Comment: OK..I set my levels in intervals of 5 though and the colorbar labels are in intervals of 15. Any way to force that to intervals of 10? I tried a couple of things that I found on here but no luck yet.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest after one allots `norm` using `BoundaryNorm`, then do we not need `vmin` and `vmax`? Even if I give the argument of `vmin`,  `vmax` it doesn't change the scale. Is it because the scale is now selected based on `norm` ?

Comment: @Light_B The scale is chosen based on the levels. The colors on the scale are chosen by `vmin/vmax` or `norm` (I think if both are given, norm should take precedence).