# Why is the difference in color bar showing up between pcolormesh and contourf plot with custom made color bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-xarray

I've adapted a custom made color scale from `NCL` following discrete intervals color bar [example](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html). My data-array is in a NetCDF file and when I try to plot it, the plot and the color bar looks as expected for `pcolormesh` plot but it goes crazy when I plot `contourf` plot. Am I doing something wrong in **defining** the color scale?

```
import matplotlib.colors
import xarray as xr

# loading data

ds = xr.open_dataset(path/tofile/data.nc)


## custom color bar
## converting RGB values to 0,1
cmap3 =  matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap([(127/255, 150/255, 255/255), (142/255, 178/255, 255/255), (181/255, 201/255, 255/255), (214/255, 226/255, 237/255),\
(242/255, 221/255, 160/255), (242/255, 132/255, 68/255), (229/255, 0/255, 0/255), (1, 163/255, 10/255), (1, 249/255, 20/255), (172/255, 206/255, 100/255), (125/255, 190/255, 84/255)])

# I want to discretize the colorbar according to values
vals = [-1.0, 0.0, 0.2 ,0.5, 0.8, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 4.0 , 6.0 , 8.0,  10]
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(vals, cmap3.N)

# variable to be plotted
ds.PV.squeeze().plot.pcolormesh(cmap=cmap3, norm=norm, vmin=0, vmax=10)
# contourf plot which is giving unexpected result
ds.PV.squeeze().plot.contourf(cmap=cmap3, norm=norm, vmin=0, vmax=10)
```

Expected colorscale with Pcolormesh plot:

[image: Pcolormesh plot with the right colorscale]

Wrong color scale when plotting contourf plot:
[image: Wrong color scale]

Below is contourf plot with default color scale
[image: Contourf with default colorscale]

This is how my **correct** color bar looks like:

```
fig, ax =plt.subplots(figsize=(6,1))

cb3 = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap3,
                            norm=norm,
                            extend='neither',
                            ticks=vals,
                            spacing='uniform',
                            orientation='horizontal')
```

[image: correct colorbar]

Comment: I guess you need to specify the `levels` explicitely. Else they will be deduced from the data and that might lead to strange results of only part of the data is to be shown. Possibly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49283519/4124317) would help you.

Comment: It would be useful to have the at least a portion of the dataset with which to work

Comment: @Ghost I don't know how to share a netcdf file here, although the file is not big. And if I share a portion of data then the result would be different as it seems like contourf overrides the intervals and picks the colorbar based on the data automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ImportanceofBeingErnest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282955/center-matplotlib-colormap-on-a-specific-value/49283519#49283519) detailed answer helped. In `contourf` one has to specifically specify the levels at which one needs to draw contours whereas `pcolormesh` seems to pick it automatically based on the colorbar

```
ds.PV.squeeze().plot.contourf(cmap=cmap3, norm=norm,levels=vals)
```

[image: Correct plot]